# resteasy ajax request

Tags: jquery, jax-rs, resteasy, cors

I have a RestEasy api, and I need to provide access to all http methods to a mobile client, all those request must be sent via ajax.

Here is an example of the client code:

```
var data = {
   login: 'usertest@gmail.com',
   password: '123456'
 };

 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://1.1.1.3:8080/api/admin',
   type: 'POST',
   contentType : 'application/json',
   dataType: "json",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   success: function(){
     console.log(arguments);
   },
   error: function(){
     console.log('error')
   }
 });
```

And here of the server:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response doLogin(User user) {...}
```

And here is the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://1.1.1.3:8080/api/admin. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here's my header answer from the server when I request from Localhost

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://1.1.1.3:8080 //request sent from http://1.1.1.3:8080
Access-Control-Expose-Hea...    X-Test-2, X-Test-1
Content-Length  1136
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 19 Dec 2012 17:54:19 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

PS: Everything works fine via usual http requests.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it with the help of a friend...I'm using the Cors Filter library from here http://software.dzhuvinov.com and I was missing one parameter at the web.xml, I fixed adding "Origin" to:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Origin, Accept, Content-Type,
            X-Requested-With</param-value>
    </init-param>
```